# CSS animation is working on desktop but not mobile?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a keyframes animation for a changing word carousel. It is working perfectly on desktop, but the animation doesn't work at all on mobile. I have tried both Safari and Chrome on mobile (and so has another user) and neither is working. Any help would be immensely appreciated! Also, the pieces of span content I am using are just placeholders.

```css
  .carousel {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .carousel h3 {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.7em;
  }

  .carousel h3:before{
    content: 'architecture';
    -webkit-animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes animate {
    0%, 100%{
      content: 'architecture';
    }
    20%{
      content: 'illustration';
    }
    40%{
      content: 'x';
    }
    60%{
      content: 'y';
    }
    80%{
      content: 'z';
    }
  }
```

```html
<span class="hero-italic">My work is inspired by </span><span class="carousel"><h3></h3></span>.</h1>
```

Comment: i checked your code in mobile format. your code works well.

Comment: It should work on most modern mobile browsers. I would recommend using `::before` instead of `:before`, as `::` represents a pseudo-element, and `:` represents a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

### Using in `animation`

---

```
-webkit-animation: animate 10s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
-moz-animation:    animate 10s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
-o-animation:      animate 10s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
 animation:         animate 10s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
```

### Using in `keyframes`

---

```
 @-webkit-keyframes animate {
    ------------------------
    ------------------------
 }
 
 @-moz-keyframes animate {
    ------------------------
    ------------------------
 }
 
 @-o-keyframes animate {
    ------------------------
    ------------------------
 }
 
 @keyframes animate {
    ------------------------
    ------------------------
 }
```

```css
  .carousel {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .carousel h3 {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.7em;
  }

  .carousel h3:before{
    content: 'architecture';
    -webkit-animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    animate 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation:      animate 10s linear infinite;
    animation:         animate 10s linear infinite;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes animate{
    0%, 100%{
      content: 'architecture';
    }
    20%{
      content: 'illustration';
    }
    40%{
      content: 'x';
    }
    60%{
      content: 'y';
    }
    80%{
      content: 'z';
    }
  }
 @keyframes animate{
    0%, 100%{
      content: 'architecture';
    }
    20%{
      content: 'illustration';
    }
    40%{
      content: 'x';
    }
    60%{
      content: 'y';
    }
    80%{
      content: 'z';
    }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes animate{
    0%, 100%{
      content: 'architecture';
    }
    20%{
      content: 'illustration';
    }
    40%{
      content: 'x';
    }
    60%{
      content: 'y';
    }
    80%{
      content: 'z';
    }
  }
 @-o-keyframes animate {
    0%, 100%{
      content: 'architecture';
    }
    20%{
      content: 'illustration';
    }
    40%{
      content: 'x';
    }
    60%{
      content: 'y';
    }
    80%{
      content: 'z';
    }
  }
```

```html
<span class="hero-italic">My work is inspired by </span><span class="carousel"><h3></h3></span>.</h1>
```

Comment: For all broswer support by adding  -webkit-,-moz,-o,etc in animation keyframs.